How to implement woocommerce order with deposit using rest api for mobile application?
I have created WooCommerce store & added products with deposits so for that i have used WooCommerce Deposit Plugin using that i have created payment plans and its working as expected on site. Now i wants to create an order in app as well so for that I tried with custom rest api but its not working, normal order without deposit is creating successfully using woocommerce Rest API but i want Deposit order as well, Could please help me with it. any document or reference something.
Thank you!
I tried using custom api in mu-plugins
add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
    register_rest_route('custom/v1', '/create-deposit-order', [
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'create_deposit_order_with_payment_plan',
        'permission_callback' => '__return_true'
    ]);
});

function create_deposit_order_with_payment_plan(WP_REST_Request $request) {
    global $wpdb;

    $params = $request->get_json_params();

    // Get order details from the request
    $customer_id = $params['customer_id'];
    $product_id = $params['product_id'];
    $quantity = $params['quantity'];
    $deposit_amount = $params['deposit_amount'];
    $payment_plan_id = $params['payment_plan_id'];

    // Retrieve the product
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);

    if (!$product || !$product->is_in_stock()) {
        return new WP_REST_Response(array(
            'message' => 'Product is not available.',
        ), 400);
    }

    // Retrieve the payment plan from wp_wc_deposits_payment_plans
    $payment_plan = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM wp_wc_deposits_payment_plans WHERE id = %d",
        $payment_plan_id
    ));

    if (!$payment_plan) {
        return new WP_REST_Response(array(
            'message' => 'Invalid payment plan.',
        ), 400);
    }

    $payment_plan_name = $payment_plan->name;  // Example: '3 months'
    $installments = substr($payment_plan_name, 0, 1);  // Number of installments

    // Check if installments is greater than zero to avoid division by zero
    if ($installments <= 0) {
        return new WP_REST_Response(array(
            'message' => 'Invalid payment plan: number of installments must be greater than zero.',
        ), 400);
    }

    // Create the main WooCommerce order
    $order = wc_create_order();

    // Get product price and calculate subtotal
    $product_price = $product->get_price();
    $subtotal = $product_price * $quantity;

    // Add product to order
    $order->add_product($product, $quantity);

    // Set customer
    $order->set_customer_id($customer_id);

    // Apply 20% VAT
    $vat_rate = 0.20;
    $vat_amount = $subtotal * $vat_rate;

    // Add VAT line item
    $order->add_order_note('20% VAT applied to the order');
    $order->add_item(array(
        'name' => 'VAT',
        'total' => $vat_amount,
        'subtotal' => $vat_amount,
        'quantity' => 1,
    ));

    // Calculate total with VAT
    $total_with_vat = $subtotal + $vat_amount;
    $order->set_total($total_with_vat);

    // Set main order status to partially paid
    $order->set_status('wc-partially-paid');

    // Use WooCommerce Deposits to handle deposit
    $order->update_meta_data('_wc_deposits_enable_deposit', 'yes');
    $order->update_meta_data('_wc_deposits_deposit_amount', $deposit_amount);

    // Save main order and get main order ID
    $order->calculate_totals();
    $order->save();
    $main_order_id = $order->get_id();
    $email = $order->get_billing_email();

    // Calculate the amount for each installment
    $installment_amount = round(($total_with_vat - $deposit_amount) / $installments, 2);  // Installment amount
    $remaining_amount = $total_with_vat - $deposit_amount;

    // Create installment (partial payment) orders based on payment plan
    for ($i = 0; $i < $installments; $i++) {
        $installment_order = wc_create_order();

        // Add installment metadata
        $installment_order->update_meta_data('parent_order_id', $main_order_id);
        $installment_order->update_meta_data('_wc_deposits_payment_plan', $payment_plan_name);

        // Set the custom order type as 'wcdp_payment'
        wp_update_post(array(
            'ID'          => $installment_order->get_id(),
            'post_type'   => 'wcdp_payment',  // Force the order type to 'wcdp_payment'
        ));

        // Add product to installment order
        $installment_order->add_product($product, $quantity);

        // For the first installment, mark as completed and set the deposit amount
        if ($i === 0) {
            $installment_order->set_status('wc-completed');
            $installment_order->set_total($deposit_amount);  // First installment is the deposit amount
        } else {
            $installment_order->set_status('wc-pending');
            $installment_order->set_total($installment_amount);  // Set total for remaining installments
        }

        // Set type to 'wcdp_payment'
        // $installment_order->update_meta_data('_order_type', 'wcdp_payment');

        // Save installment order
        $installment_order->save();

        $installment_order_id = $installment_order->get_id();

        // Table name (with the WordPress table prefix)
        $table_name = 'wp_wc_orders';

        // Data to update
        $data = array(
            'type' => 'wcdp_payment',
            'parent_order_id' => $main_order_id,
            'customer_id' => $customer_id,
            'email' => $email,
        );

        // Where condition (the row to update)
        $where = array('id' => $installment_order_id,);

        // Format for the data
        $data_format = array('%s', '%d', '%d', '%s');

        // Format for the where condition
        $where_format = array('%d');

        // Update the data in the table
        $updated = $wpdb->update( $table_name, $data, $where, $data_format, $where_format );
    }

    // Return main order ID in the response
    return new WP_REST_Response(array(
        'main_order_id' => $main_order_id,
        'email' => $email,
        'message' => 'Main order and partial payments created successfully with payment plan.'
    ), 200);
}

enter image description here

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
